# Error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file in Docker

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to build an image with stunnel.

My base image OS is,

> Linux 2338b11efbe1 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 16:55:56 UTC
>   2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Installing libssl as below.

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev && \
    ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10 && \
    ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

Below command lists the libs.

> RUN ls libssl.so.* libcrypto.so*

Output ------>>>

```
libcrypto.so.10
libssl.so.10
```

Still, below command fails.

> RUN ./stunnel

**Error :-**

> ./stunnel: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Am i missing any other instruction here.

Here is my complete dockerfile.

```
from <BASE_IMAGE>
COPY stunnel .
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev && \
    ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10 && \
    ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
RUN ./stunnel
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] rather than a few of the commands? A complete Dockerfile that doesn't depend on other unshared files to ADD and COPY in would allow us to reproduce this.

Comment: Is `stunnel` built against OpenSSL 1.1.0 or 1.0.2? They are _not_ binary compatible, and you must have the correct one installed on the system. Also see [How does the versioning scheme work?](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#MISC) in the OpenSSL FAQ.

Comment: @jww - When i ran stunnel, it was looking for libssl.so.10. I believe it is using libssl/so.1.0.0.  My stunnel verison is 5.40.

Comment: @BMitch - I have updated the dockerfile.

Comment: @user1578872 that unfortunately won't build for me. I don't have that base image, and the next copy command will fail without a `stunnel` binary that I don't know how you created/downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

The failure mode suggests that your `libssl.so.10` is a broken symlink. Meaning the file `libssl.so.1.0.0` does not exist.

A command such as `ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10` will succeed even if the target of the symlink does not (yet) exist. Plain `ls` on the broken symlinks will not report anything untoward either.

If you want to be sure the symlinks are not broken, check each symlink with `test -e`.

More specifically using `ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10` as some kind of 'fix' indicates you have other issues: the version component of a soname consists of abi-version.patch-level.backwards-compatibility fields and this is used by the loader to determine whether or not a given library file (symlinked or otherwise) could possibly match the library requested by the application. As you can see, using `ln` you are claiming that ABI version 1 is the same as ABI version 10. That may not work as expected.

Finally, your `ln` commands use relative paths so you are probably working in the wrong directory -- hence why you end up creating broken symlinks. On Debian based systems `libssl.so` can typically be found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. The `x86_64-linux-gnu` bit depends on architecture (as defined by Debian multi arch support), this particular example is valid for 64 bit x86 code.

Comment: I have the following libs under /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/   1.libssl.a
2.libssl.so
3.libssl.so.0.9.8
4.libssl3.so. Why it is not picking the exsting lib?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when I installed RStudio on Ubuntu 19.10. It complained not finding libssl.so.1.0.0 and libcrypto.so.1.0.0. After sometime, I tried to locate if these files where installed on my system as trying to install them manually never worked. I used the `locate` command like so:
`locate libssl`

[This image shows the output of the locate command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNDd.png)

The output showed that the 'missing' libraries were actually installed on my system.
Then I tried to look in the `lib` (that is `/lib/` directory) folder but never found these files. So I tried to copy them inferring their paths from the output of the locate command into the `/lib/` directory as follows:

`$sudo cp /snap/core/7917/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /lib/`

I did the same for the `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` lib file.

Then I tried to run RStudio again and it worked.

I hope this helps you. But be careful that you don't overwrite any files, otherwise you may end up with an unstable system.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the binary package file from this link https://rosa.pkgs.org/2014.1/rosa-main-updates-x86_64/lib64crypto1.0.0-1.0.2q-1-rosa2014.1.x86_64.rpm.html and copy the libcrypto.so.1.0.0 file to /usr/lib
That solves the problem!